# Create fillable PDF form with exams2nops

Tags: r-exams

We think about distributing an open-book exam as a **fillable PDF form** via `exams2nops`. The idea is that students do not print the PDF and mark their answers with a pen, but rather fill in their answers electronically in their PDF (e.g. with Acrobat Reader), and send back that PDF to us (or upload it via Moodle). Then, the PDF is "scanned" / the answers are extracted from the PDF.

Currently, the checkboxes for MC/SC answers are not clickable; also the textfields for free text answers could be fillable text input fields. The current PDF export does not do this.

Has anybody done this already? If I'd like to implement this, where is a good starting point? Maybe nops.tex?

(We are aware that exporting to an interactive quiz in Moodle is an alternative option).

Comment: This is not supported out of the box. It is probably doable with some effort, though. But I don't see any advantages in using this approach over an exam in Moodle. What is your reasoning?

Comment: Advantages of Moodle over the PDF: You have standard authentication via the Moodle login. Moodle extracts and evaluates the answers automatically vs you having to write code for that for the PDF. Moodle has more question types readily built-in. // The usual advantage of _printed_ PDF over Moodle is that it's robust/low-tech (you can't have any server crashes) and students have no/less access to technology that can be used for cheating. But all of this does not apply if you fill in the PDF electronically.

Comment: Oh, and many PDF forms require Acrobat to work reliably (or at all) and this isn't available on all platforms. Moodle just requires a modern browser.

Comment: These are all good arguments. Main reason why we explore this route is that it is semi-low-tech: You only need Internet connection during download of PDF and upload at the end of the exam period; it does not depend on a reliable Moodle environment.

Comment: I suggest too you should use `exams2moodle`. Many pdf-reader doesn't support pdf-forms (I don't know about Android's readers) but the modern browsers support HTML's checkbox in Moodle :) The student's workflow will simplier: don't need download, edit and upload a pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- `exams2nops()` does not support this and will not be extended in this direction because its focus is generating PDF exams for printing/scanning/etc.
- `exams2pdf()` can be customized to use different LaTeX templates and you can try to set up a suitable template using the `{hyperref}` package.
- The support for the resulting PDF forms differs a lot between PDF viewers, typically with Acrobat Reader being the only one with decent support.
- My personal experience with the heterogeneity on students' systems plus sending solutions via e-mail is that this is not a very reliable solution but would be the source of a lot of problems. Personally, I would avoid going down this road.
- If your university hosts a Moodle system, I would recommend generating exams via `exams2moodle()`. At least the responsibility for the stability of the system is then with the university.

**Details:**

By using the `{hyperref}` package you can use the `{Form}` environment with commands like `\CheckBox{}`, `\TextEntry{}`, etc. A brief overview is given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs

A more elaborate worked example is available at: https://martin-thoma.com/creating-pdf-forms-with-latex/

Based on these I adapted the `exam.tex` template provided within the R/exams package and set up a `form.tex` template. The full LaTeX code is included below. This tries to do the following:

- Set up a form that can be submitted by e-mail when completed.
- The form consists of "fixed" fields for name and student ID.
- Then it sets up commands `\exnum`, `\exstring`, `exmchoice` etc. that can be used by `exams2pdf()`. See Section 3 in `vignette("exams", package = "exams")` for details. Thus, these commands are repeated as often as necessary for a given exam.
- At the end there are buttons to "Submit" or "Clear" the form.

For illustration, try:

```
exams2pdf(
  c("deriv.Rmd", "swisscapital.Rmd", "boxplots.Rmd", "ttest.Rmd", "function.Rmd", "lm.Rmd"),
  template = "form.tex"
)
```

where `form.tex` from below needs to be in your current working directory.

The result is a `form1.pdf` displayed automatically in your default PDF viewer (see `options(pdfviewer = ...)`). Alternatively, you can also add an argument `dir = "."` to store the file in your current working directory.

For me on Debian GNU/Linux with TeXLive this works and produces a PDF file that can be viewed and filled in using the Evince PDF viewer. However, neither "Submit" nor "Clear" works.

When I open the same file under Acrobat Reader in Windows 10, then only the TextEntry fields for Name/ID work, the others don't. The check boxes work but all checkboxes for (a) are linked, as are all (b), etc.

My impression is that composing the `{Form}` on the fly like this does not work for Acrobat Reader. But I would appreciate pointers how this can be fixed. An alternative would be to exactly code the form you need for a specific exam with unique `name` tags in all form elements etc.

**Bonus note:**

The template below also activates the `{attachfile}` LaTeX package which can be used to embed files (e.g., data sets) into the PDF. This works for me but only under Acrobat Reader. To automatically convert all `\url{}` commands (as created for the `lm` exercise, used above) into `\attachfile{}` commands, the development version of `exams2pdf()` gained an argument `attachfile = FALSE` which can be set to `TRUE`. See this thread in the R/exams forum on R-Forge for more details:
https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=32091&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337

**LaTeX template:** `form.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%% packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide,color,verbatim,Sweave,url,xargs,amsmath,booktabs,longtable,eurosym}

%%% %% optionally: two-column layout for exercise form
%%% \usepackage{multicol}

%% embed supplementary data files etc.
\usepackage{attachfile}
\attachfilesetup{color=0.5 0 0}

%% support PDF forms
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% new environments
\newenvironment{question}{\item}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}

%% paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0.7ex plus0.1ex minus0.1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

%% compatibility with pandoc
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}

%% fonts: Helvetica
\usepackage{helvet}
\IfFileExists{sfmath.sty}{
  \RequirePackage[helvet]{sfmath}
}{}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

\newcommandx{\exmchoice}[9][2=-,3=-,4=-,5=-,6=-,7=-,8=-,9=-]{%
                \CheckBox[name=a, width=1em]{(a)}~~%
  \if #2- \else \CheckBox[name=b, width=1em]{(b)}~~ \fi%
  \if #3- \else \CheckBox[name=c, width=1em]{(c)}~~ \fi%
  \if #4- \else \CheckBox[name=d, width=1em]{(d)}~~ \fi%
  \if #5- \else \CheckBox[name=e, width=1em]{(e)}~~ \fi%
  \if #6- \else \CheckBox[name=f, width=1em]{(f)}~~ \fi%
  \if #7- \else \CheckBox[name=g, width=1em]{(g)}~~ \fi%
  \if #8- \else \CheckBox[name=h, width=1em]{(h)}~~ \fi%
  \if #9- \else \CheckBox[name=i, width=1em]{(i)}~~ \fi%
}
\newcommandx{\exclozechoice}[9][2=-,3=-,4=-,5=-,6=-,7=-,8=-,9=-]{\setcounter{enumiii}{1}%
                \CheckBox[name=ca, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii}%
  \if #2- \else \CheckBox[name=cb, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #3- \else \CheckBox[name=cc, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #4- \else \CheckBox[name=cd, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #5- \else \CheckBox[name=ce, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #6- \else \CheckBox[name=cf, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #7- \else \CheckBox[name=cg, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #8- \else \CheckBox[name=ch, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.} \stepcounter{enumiii} \fi%
  \if #9- \else \CheckBox[name=ci, width=1em]{\roman{enumiii}.}  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\exnum}[9]{\TextField[name=num, width=4cm]{}}
\newcommand{\exstring}[1]{\TextField[name=string, width=4cm]{}}

%% new commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ID}[1]{\def\@ID{#1}}
\newcommand{\Date}[1]{\def\@Date{#1}}
\ID{00001}
\Date{YYYY-MM-DD}

%% \exinput{header}

\newcommand{\myID}{\@ID}
\newcommand{\myDate}{\@Date}
\makeatother

%% headings
\markboth{\textnormal{\bf \large Statistics Exam: \myID}}%
{\textnormal{\bf \large Statistics Exam: \myID}}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

%% title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\sf
\textbf{\LARGE{R University}}

\textbf{\large{Statistics Exam \myDate \hfill Exam ID \myID}}

\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{Form}[action=mailto:info@example.com,encoding=html,method=post]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{Name}       & \TextField[name=Name, width=10cm]{}\\
\textbf{Student ID} & \TextField[name=ID, width=10cm]{}\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{1cm}

%%% \begin{multicols}{2}

%% \exinput{questionnaire}

%%% \end{multicols}

\Submit{Submit} ~~ \Reset{Clear}

\end{Form}
}
\newpage

\begin{enumerate}

%% \exinput{exercises}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @FelixS: Late to the party, but I am setting up a similar workflow at the moment. No emails sent, but students can download the PDF in different variants, managed by Moodle groups. Students then upload an Excel file, where they have filled in their answers. Let me know in case you are interested in details.

Answer (score 1):

we will structure our exam like this:

- students download pdf created with exams2nops
- students open pdfs with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (free: https://get.adobe.com/de/reader/?promoid=P79NQR4R&mv=other) and mark the boxes with X via the "sign" option
- students upload the first filled page of the exam back (via print to pdf). The advantage of this is that the set crosses can no longer be changed.
- normal evaluation process of exams starts...